# No properties are generated with Android SDK

Tags: android, android-layout, sdk

I installed packages from the Android SDK manager, but when I open an xml file to edit a layout, I get unresolved errors When I drag and drop items from the sidebar, I get a log saying:

```
 Couldn't resolve resource @dimen/activity_horizontal_margin
 Couldn't resolve resource @dimen/activity_vertical_margin
 "@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" in attribute "paddingLeft" is not a valid format.
 "@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" in attribute "paddingTop" is not a valid format.
 "@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" in attribute "paddingRight" is not a valid format.
 "@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" in attribute "paddingBottom" is not a valid format.
```

Also, no properties show up when I view the menu. When I right click on the layout to set a different layout manager, I see the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7j5f.jpg). I installed the correct packages from the SDK Manager, including all tools, the Android 19 API, Android 18 API, and the Android Support library.

Here's my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Where can I start by fixing these errors?

Comment: pls post your xml file

Comment: I have updated my xml file.

Comment: What is the value for @dimen/activity_vertical_margin... ? 16dp or ??
Seems to be some other error due to which your R file is not generating...check resource folder for errors elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by a mix-and-match of some large, medium and small resolutions in your project but render the layout in a view not considered large enough. In this case, just change the render parameter in the graphical layout tool. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Such layout errors usually appears after you've created new Activities/Layouts using IDE build-in tools/wizards (like `New->Activity->Blank Activity with Fragment` in Android Studio). At this moment Java and XML code is already created, but auto-generated code (like `R.java` file) isn't generated yet. What's why layout editing feature is not working - it requires valid `R.java` file with all your resources (in your case it's `@dimen/*`).

To fix this errors simply **compile your project** (which will force auto-generated code to be generated) and refresh layout editor window.